# Hibernate criteria return page and rowcount

Tags: java, hibernate

Using Hibernate Criteria i am trying to achieve pagination but the problem is that for every page fetch i have to make two db calls one for results and another for total records count.
Is there any efficient way so that in a single db call i can get both the data or i can reduce db calls.

```
 Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Student.class);
 criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("enquiryStatus", ENQUIRY.JOINED));
 criteria.setMaxResults(10);
 criteria.setFirstResult((paginate.getStartIndex()-1)*10);

 criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
//here i need to fetch total row count and records
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes you need the separate query to get the total result count.

```
    Query aCountQuery  = session.createQuery("select count(s.id) from Student s 
           where s.enquiryStatus != :enquiryStatus");
           aCountQuery.setParameter("enquiryStatus", ENQUIRY.JOINED);
    Long resultCount = (Long)aCountQuery.uniqueResult();
```

or

```
   Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Student.class);
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("enquiryStatus", ENQUIRY.JOINED));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
   Long resultCount = (Long)criteria.uniqueResult();
```

**Update**

Now you can use same Criteria for results with pagination and result count

```
  Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Student.class);
     criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
     criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("enquiryStatus", ENQUIRY.JOINED));
     criteria.setMaxResults(10);
     criteria.setFirstResult((paginate.getStartIndex()-1)*10);
     List<Student> students = criteria.list();

    criteria.setProjection(null);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    Long resultCount = (Long)criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Yes i agree with you guys  but what if the query is so complex and it has so many restrictions then we need to duplicate the db call.If there is any alternative approach please help

Comment: Loading whole to list to get count ?? Strange ... ^_^

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ yes accepted... for that situation we need to go with...  Long resultCount = (Long)aCountQuery.uniqueResult();

Comment: @Prabhakaran Yes.If Dinesh is using your first attempt(simple query),It's efficient :) +1.

Comment: How good the performance will be between having a separate query and doing like this for finding total rows? (Considering as second request, with hibernate cache enabled)

Answer (score 1):

As far As I know there is no direct method  to do so.As simple as you can do is write a small `hql query`(my choice) ,Along with your main `criteria`.

```
Number count = (Number) session.createQuery(
    "select count(s.id) from Student s").uniqueResult();
```