# How to get the count of individual records from mysql using Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to fetch the count of all individual records from mysql database using hibernate and I have to store it in a map collection. How to do this?

```
try {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    String hql = "select attendencestatus ,COUNT(attendencestatus) from studentattendance group by attendencestatus ";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);     
    tx.commit();

} catch (HibernateException he) {
    he.printStackTrace();
    tx.rollback();
}
```

Comment: isn't [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate) helpful? or may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484988/hibernate-criteria-return-page-and-rowcount)?

Answer (score 1):

```
--------------------------------------
|   ID    |CountryName|  CurrencyName|
|_________|___________|______________|
|   1     | India     |   Rupees     |
|   2     | India     |   Rupees     |
|   3     | India     |   Rupees     |
|   4     | Usa       |   dollar     |
|   5     | dubai     |   AED        |
|   6     | Germany   |   Euro       |
|--------------------------------------

String hql="select anyColmnName from entity;
 Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
 List<string> list=query.list();
int countOfRecords=Collections.frequency(list, value)
```

**Example**

```
  String hql="select  countryName from Revenue;
     Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
     List<string> list=query.list();
    int countOfRecords=Collections.frequency(list, "India")
```